# how to crop top,left,right and bottom portion of imageview in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

In my application i am getting transparent pixels in my Imageview while taking screenshot.How to cut top,left,right[image] and bottom portion of Imageview.I tried below code but not working

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgView.getWidth(),imgView.getHeight(),                   Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
imgView.draw(canvas);
Bitmap result =Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,imgView.getLeft()+10, imgView.getTop()+50,    imgView.getWidth()-20, imgView.getHeight()-100);
 bitmap.recycle();
```

please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you please define "I tried below code but not working"? How is it not working? Exceptions? Image not cropped correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure what are you referring with "not working", but from first sight I would suggest you to change from

```
Bitmap result =Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,imgView.getLeft()+10, imgView.getTop()+50,    imgView.getWidth()-20, imgView.getHeight()-100);
```

to

```
Bitmap result =Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 10, 50, bitmap.getWidth()-20, bitmap.getHeight()-100);
```

But I would not recommend you to use this kind of approach which explicitly setting width and height value.

Comment: is it possible to know transparent pixels from bitmap and crop that transparent pixels

Comment: I do not know any, but it seems there is a bitmap.getpixel method which may return you something useful, but it will be a very long loop.

Comment: If you can, use `ImageView` instead of a `Bitmap` and you could use `ImageView.adjustViewBounds(true);` which clips surrounding transparent edges.